# Multiple Commands in For loop - Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have multiple folders where each folder got a zip file and i have a zip file extracting utility.this utility is command line based.i have tried the below, i want the batch to extract files in all folders.

`for /f %%a in ('DIR g:\folder\ /b') do ( CD %%a
g:\utility\7za e file_%%a.zip
)`

Thanks

Comment: And where it fails? It could be useful to describe your current problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is unclear but this enters every folder in the `g:\folder\` directory
and extracts `"file_apple.zip"` in the `g:\folder\apple` directory etc.

You may need to use the `x` switch of 7za instead of the `e` switch to retain folder structure.

```
@echo off
cd /d "g:\folder\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /ad /b') do (
   CD "%%a" 
   "g:\utility\7za" e "file_%%a.zip"
   cd ..
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In other words you have:

(example)
g:\folder\folder1

you want to change to that directory, then extract
file_folder1.zip
?

If you just want to extract all of the zip files beginning with file_ ,
just change your second line to

g:\utility\7za e file_*.zip